# Ratio of large binomials in matlab

Tags: binomial-coefficients, matlab, factorial

I need to compute the following ratio
$$ \frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}/ \frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/2)!}$$
I've tried to do this using nchoosek which works finte until $n\approx1000$.
But I need at least $n\approx 10000$.

Is it possible to reformulate the equation in terms of "gammaln" and exponentiate the ratio at the end again? or maybe there is an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have no way except using approximations! One good one is the Stirling's approximation for factorial:$$n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot \left({n\over e}\right)^n$$in that case you can further write$$\frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}/ \frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/2)!}{=\frac{1}{j!(n-j)!}/ \frac{1}{(n/2)!(n/2)!}\\\approx \frac{{\sqrt{\pi n}\cdot \left({n\over 2e}\right)^{n}}}{j!(n-j)!}}$$you can apply Stirling's approximation for $j!$ and $(n-j)!$ whenever needed.

Comment: thank you. but what about numerical overflow? The terms in the denominator can become huge

Comment: Your welcome. In that case you can use $$j!(n-j)!\approx 2\pi\sqrt{j(n-j)}({j\over e})^j({n-j\over e})^{n-j}$$. Of course it is much better to know the magnitude of $j$ and $n$ as much as possible (for example such that $j<<n$) to proceed with more approximations. Also I checked @gt989b's answer and it looked nice to me, but requires a high computation time using a **for** loop (I'll try to enhance my own approximation more than this).

Comment: **P.S.**   With an approximation for $j!(n-j)!$ you can cancel $e^n$ in both numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $n$ is even so $n/2 = m$ and $j \le m$ (otherwise $n-j < m$) you get
$$
\frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!} \div \frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/2)!}
 = \frac{(n/2)!(n/2)!}{j!(n-j)!}
 = \frac{(j+1) \times \ldots \times m}{(m+1) \times \ldots \times (2m-j)}
$$
both numerator and denominator are straight integer products, should be quite quick to compute.

Comment: To avoid numerical overflow, it's better to compute this as
$$ \frac{j+1}{m+1} \cdot \frac{j+2}{m+2} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{m}{2m-j} $$

Comment: thanks for the solution and the hint.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your suggestions and they do work. gt6989b's solution is fast enough if you use matlab's "prod" which is vectorized. However, the restriction $j\leq m$ is quite severe.

Anyway, I've tried another approach:

```
    result=exp(2*gammaln(n/2+1)-gammaln(j+1)-gammaln(N-j+1));
```

This works surprisingly fast but has an error of order $\approx 10^{-14}$